# Creating a column in runtime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a **Query**

```
select Distinct EmailAddress as MailId  from tblUsers
```

it shows the emails, but i want to create a column through the query which will show total number of emails.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER ()
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmailAddress
    FROM tblUsers
) t
```

Just for R&D -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetCount ()
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EmailAddress) FROM tblUsers)
END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblUsers
    ADD TotalCnt AS dbo.udf_GetCount() PERSISTED
GO
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmailAddress, t.TotalCnt
FROM tblUsers
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT TotalCnt = COUNT(DISTINCT EmailAddress)
    FROM tblUsers
) t
```

Comment: is it possible to provide a column name to the column showing total number,

Comment: Possible, but why you need that? Windows functions are more convenient ;)

Comment: Just doing some R & D. Increasing knowledge

Comment: Thanks to you @Devart

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE #email
(
    email VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO #email VALUES
('a.c@s'),
('a.c@s'),
('b.c@s'),
('b.c@s'),
('c.c@s'),
('c.c@s'),
('d.c@s');
```

If you want count of each email, then

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS [Count]
FROM #email
GROUP BY email;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-------+
| email | Count |
+-------+-------+
| a.c@s | 2     |
| b.c@s | 2     |
| c.c@s | 2     |
| d.c@s | 1     |
+-------+-------+
```

else count of total distinct email

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email)  FROM #email) AS [Count]
FROM #email;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-------+
| email | Count |
+-------+-------+
| a.c@s | 4     |
| b.c@s | 4     |
| c.c@s | 4     |
| d.c@s | 4     |
+-------+-------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10400/2)

Comment: The Second one is not working, FIrst one is fine @Ullas

Comment: @Arka : Its working fine for me. Please check it once again.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT email, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email)  FROM                  #email) AS [Count]
FROM #email ` Its showing error on the "email" word

Comment: @Arka : Updated the answer with a working sql fiddle demo.